# C#: How to correctly use FFT to determine waveform similarity?

Tags: c#, fft, naudio, aforge

I have 2 stereo ADPCM waveforms. 1st is the original waveform and the 2nd is a 10 second trim of the original waveform.
I need to find the timestamp in milliseconds where 2nd clip starts in the 1st clip.

I did some research and found out that FFT is the way to go. However I'm very new to DSP so I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

I am using `NAudio 1.7.3` to convert the waveform to PCM and `AForge 2.2.5` to perform the FFT.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
// ADPCM -> PCM -> Wave32
// 44.1khz 16bits 2ch
using (var song = new WaveFileReader(songFile))
using (var songuncompressed = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(song))
using (var songwav = new WaveChannel32(songuncompressed))
using (var preview = new WaveFileReader(previewFile))
using (var previewuncompressed = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(preview))
using (var prevwav = new WaveChannel32(previewuncompressed))
{
    // Read files into buffer
    var prebuffer = new byte[prevwav.Length];
    var songbuffer = new byte[songwav.Length];
    prevwav.Read(prebuffer, 0, (int)prevwav.Length);
    songwav.Read(songbuffer, 0, (int)songwav.Length);

    // byte[] -> float[]
    float[] prefloats = new float[prebuffer.Length / sizeof(float)];
    float[] songfloats = new float[songbuffer.Length / sizeof(float)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(prebuffer, 0, prefloats, 0, prebuffer.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(songbuffer, 0, songfloats, 0, songbuffer.Length);

    int FFTSize = 1024;
    int increment = prefloats.Length / FFTSize; // Not sure if this is correct?
    double step = songwav.Length / songwav.TotalTime.TotalMilliseconds / 4; //float per millisecond
    double smallest = double.MaxValue;
    int millisecond = 0;

    var presample = new Complex[FFTSize];
    var songsample = new Complex[FFTSize];

    // Preview data
    for (int a = 0; a < FFTSize; a++)
        presample[a] = new Complex(prefloats[a * increment], 0);

    FourierTransform.FFT(presample, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);

    // Sliding fft (1ms per step)
    for (double pos=0; pos < (double)songfloats.Length; pos += step)
    {
        int offset = (int)pos;

        // Song data
        for (int b = 0; b < FFTSize; b++)
        {
            // Check for overflow
            // Fill remaining samples with 0 if overflow
            int idx = Math.Min(b * increment + offset, songfloats.Length);

            if(idx != songfloats.Length)
                songsample[b] = new Complex(songfloats[idx], 0);
            else
                songsample[b] = new Complex(0, 0);
        }

        FourierTransform.FFT(songsample, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);

        // Simple comparison through magnitude difference
        // Not sure if it is the right way to compare results
        double similarity = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < FFTSize; i++)
        {
            similarity += Math.Abs(presample[i].Magnitude - songsample[i].Magnitude);
        }

        if(similarity < smallest)
        {
            smallest = similarity;
            int bytes = (int)pos * 4; // bytes position
            // bytes / bytesPerMS for actual millisecond
            millisecond = bytes / (int)(songwav.Length / songwav.TotalTime.TotalMilliseconds); 
        }
    }

    // Result is +- 200ms
    return millisecond;
}
```

3 things that I'm not very sure about:

1. Is this the right way to sample the data?
2. What is the correct method to compare FFT for similarity?
3. How does FFTSize affect the results?

Comment: Normally you would use [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) for a task such as this, which can be implemented with or without using FFTs.

Comment: Did you solve this?